# what is java code for continuous scanning and auto save?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to revised the existing code from using button for scan and save of qr code to continuous scanning and auto-save after scanning the qr code.

Comment: Hi Shiela. Welcome to Stack Overflow & hope you are having a pleasant day. Broad questions about how to create an app are not permitted. If you  get stuck on any *specific* aspect of creating the app please post your source code in accordance with these helpful guidelines: [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Kind Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.